# JavaScript append a select menu option to a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, appendchild

As a complete novice in JavaScript I figured out how to make the number of the selected objects from a drop down menu appear in a `<div>`. But I'm trying to figure out how to make the text selected in the drop menu appear in a `<div>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('question1');
    var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('displayresponse');
    eSelect.onchange = function() {
        if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 2) {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';

            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.innerHTML = eSelect.selectedIndex;
            var ul = document.getElementById("appendedtext");
            ul.appendChild(li); 

        } else {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'none';
        } 
    } 
}
```

```
<body>
<select id="question1" name="question">
    <option value="x">Reason 1</option>
    <option value="y">Reason 2</option>
    <option value="other">Other Reason</option>
</select>
<div id="displayresponse" style="display: none;">Response here</div>
<ol id="appendedtext"> </ol>
```

Comment: Your example only seems to show the index if the last option is selected. Two questions. 1) Do you want the value, or the text of the option to be displayed (e.g. "other" vs "Other Reason"). 2) do you want this to work for any option, or just the last one as your example above?

Comment: 1.the text of the option 2.any option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option")` in conjunction with `options[eSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML;`, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var eSelect = document.getElementById('question1');
    var optOtherReason = document.getElementById('displayresponse');

    // the option elements
    var options = document.getElementsByTagName("option");

    eSelect.onchange = function() {
        if(eSelect.selectedIndex === 2) {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'block';

            var li = document.createElement("li");

            // eSelect.selectedIndex is the index (call it `n`) of the option
            // get that `n`-th option element from `options`
            // get its `.innerHTML`
            // and set to `li.innerHTML`
            li.innerHTML = options[eSelect.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

            var ul = document.getElementById("appendedtext");
            ul.appendChild(li);
        } else {
            optOtherReason.style.display = 'none';
        } 
    } 
}
```

## EDIT:

If you want to display every change:

1. in the ordered list- http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/6h9TT/3/
2. in the `div` - http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/6h9TT/4/

Comment: @fzzle Ok, I thought those `if`s were not to be touched. I have configured it now as to [display every change](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/6h9TT/3/). And it works. I hope you are satisfied.

Comment: @fzzle And have added some options for the OP. See my answer edit.

Comment: @fzzle I had asked to look at the ones given in the edit. Please have a look at them. `DEMO` removed.

Comment: @fzzle Please explain how it doesn't work? Meaning: 1) Does it not work at all? (console errors, if any?) 2) It does not show output on selecting another option? 3) Some other. I am sorry but I can not recreate the problem.

Comment: @fzzle Please explain. I am waiting for your response.

Comment: The edit works. I really appreciate you guys. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
var select = document.getElementById('question1'),
    response = document.getElementById('displayresponse');
select.onchange = function() {
    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
    response.innerHTML = selectedOption;
    response.style.display = 'inline';
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCtK5/3/)</kbd>